# I need help finding a way to create a layout in android

Tags: android, layout

I'm sorry. I'm being very vague on my question, but I'm not sure what to search to accomplish the layout I want to. Here's a sketch of what I'm wanting to do:

[image: sketch]

Basically, what I'm trying to do is recreate a standard booking app, and I'd like to know how can I recreate the part showing each room. I'd like some help how to create the layout to show 1 room and how to repeat that layout multiple times.

Comment: Add your images inline to your post.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, It's a basic layout of android,so just do it yourself first, if you get any problem, we always stay here to help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ListView` or `RecyclerView`

Here is an example

https://uniqsofts.com/android-tutorials/android-listview-example